# Android: Change Images On pressing Previous and NExt imageview

Tags: android

Android. i am a newbie I have 6 images. One image view, two buttons previous and next. Have written the program, but when executing, crashes. I have written the logic of how to change the images in image view, I have removed all the syntax errors.  here is my Mainactivity.java code

```
package com.example.hm2_koppineedi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView imageView;
Button previous,next;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    previous = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    previous.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    next.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
 }

    public void onClick(View view) 
    {

    int a=0;
    switch (view.getId())
    {
            case R.id.button2:
            if (a == 0)
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.hdimage);
                a = 1;
            }
            else if (a == 1)
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.elephant);
                a = 2;
            }
            else if (a == 2)
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.giraffe);
                a = 3;
            }
            else if (a == 3)
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.horse);
                a = 4;
            }
            else if (a == 4)
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lion);
                a = 5;
            }
            else if (a == 5)
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tiger);
                a = 6;
            }
            else if (a == 6)

            break;  
        case R.id.button1:
                a--;
                button2.performClick();
                next.performClick();


            break;
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: post your logact please...

Comment: can you please post the Logcat..

Answer (score 0):

Wrong code:

```
previous.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
next.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

Use this:

```
previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      //...
    }
);
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      //...
    }
);
```

Comment: @Lal to use setOnClickListener(this) you should implements your Activity OnClickListener

Comment: oh..ok ok...SO i think thats the easiest solution...;)

Comment: @Lal but! if you use your solution you will have some problems with prev/next difference, but it is easy to fix.

Comment: Friends, i tried implmenting the above code, but the app crashes again !

Comment: @vikaskoppineedi give me Log out

Comment: @Lal if this answer was helpful, please vote up and accept it. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override the OnClick method, and make sure it is in your activity.

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {
...
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something
    }
...
}
```

You should not have to cast "this", but call...

```
setOnClickListener(this);
```

...from inside one of your activity methods (for instance : OnCreate), so that "this" be the activity. That way, all calls to "Click" in the context of your activity will be sent to your OnClick method.

You have lots of examples on this site to show that.